# Sympy does not update series coefficients

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sympy

```
aa = list(symbols('a0:2'))
q1= series(aa[0]/(1-x) + aa[1]/(1-x**2),x,n=6)
q1.subs(aa[0],1)  
print(q1)
Output: x**2*(a0 + a1) + x**4*(a0 + a1) + a1 + a0 + a0*x + a0*x**3 + a0*x**5 + O(x**6)
```

But what I would like for all the a0's in the series to be substitued by the value of 1:

```
Output: x**2*(1 + a1) + x**4*(1 + a1) + a1 + 1 + 1*x + 1*x**3 + 1*x**5 + O(x**6)
```

My understanding is that:

```
q1.subs(aa[0],1)
```

would do exactly that. Is there any other way to do the same ? Thanks!

Comment: `subs` produces a new expression.  It does not modify `q1` itself.  Try `q2 = q1.subs(...); print(q2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of mutable matrices, SymPy objects are immutable. Their methods do not modify them; a new  object is returned instead. This object needs to be assigned to something (or printed, or returned):

```
q2 = q1.subs(...)
print(q1.subs(...))
return q1.subs(...)
```

all make sense; the lonely `q1.subs(...)` is useless.

This is covered in the "Gotchas and Pitfalls" article under [Immutability of Expressions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#immutability-of-expressions); I recommend reading the rest of that page too.